# Defining machine-independent datatypes in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to do this?

```
#if sizeof(int) == 4
typedef unsigned int Integer32;
#else
typedef unsigned long Integer32;
#endif
```

or do you have to just #define integer size and compile different headers in?

Comment: There's already `int32_t` etc.

Comment: Oh is that a C++ standard?  Which standard because the compiler I use (Keil uVision 4) is pretty old.  Can't check it right now...

Comment: *If* you wanted to do such a thing, you should do it with template specialization and type traits. But of course you should just `#include <cstdint>`.

Comment: Nevermind it's C99, not sure if it will work or not

Comment: With Keil you'll have more problems than that. Why are you using it? Developing for a specific micro controller? Then you should know the sizes of your data types very well.

Comment: For a library that works on different machines, mainly going from there to Windows a lot.

Comment: I thought `size_t` is more usable for defining `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need **exact** sizes you can use the `intXX_t` and `uintXX_t` variants, where XX is 8, 16, 32, or 64.

If you need types that are **at least** some size, use `int_leastXX_t` and `uint_leastXX_t`;

if you need **fast**, use `int_fastXX_t` and `uint_fastXX_t`.

You get these from `<stdint.h>`, which came in with C99. If you don't have C99 it's a little harder. You can't use `sizeof(int)` because the preprocessor doesn't know about types. So use `INT_MAX` (from `<limits.h>`, etc. to figure out whether a particular type is large enough for what you need.

Comment: Ok so if Keil doesn't support C99 I can use the preprocessor and check the size in limits.h and then define types based on that?  Ok thank you!

Comment: @RyanBrown - yes, that will work. You could also do some template programming using `std::numeric_limits`, but that's probably needlessly complicated.